# optimizing sql xml select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization, xquery-sql

### XML

```
<Data>
  <Language Name="ru-Ru">
    <Item Id="1">value</Item>
    <Item Id="2">value2</Item>
  </Language>
</Data>
```

Is it possible to run it somehow like this, to simply query:

```
SELECT id, 
       userId, 
       data.query('//Language[@Name="ru-Ru"]') AS myxml
  FROM UserData
 WHERE (myxml.query('//Item[@Id="9"]') like '%v%')
```

all in all I need parameter comparison to each item and do not want to repeat

> '//Language[@Name="ru-Ru"]'

in each condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not reuse aliased columns in where clause. You can use `cross apply` to do what you want. And you need to cast your where clause to be able to use `like`.

```
select
  id, 
  userId, 
  myxml
from @T
  cross apply
    (select data.query('//Language[@Name="ru-Ru"]')) as lang(myxml)
where cast(myxml.query('//Item[@Id="9"]') as varchar(max)) like '%v%'
```

Comment: And to help with your performance, you should try to avoid the `//Language` XPath expression - try using a more specific expression with the `//` in it! Something like : `/Data/Language`